# Swing application hangs on reconnect if invoked remotely

Tags: java, swing, remote-access

I am working on swing application, and application is stop responding if user will invoke application remotely(application installed on shared path and user is trying to invoke application from his machine), and there is internet/LAN drop. In console i am getting below errors:

```
Z:\application\jre1.7.0_55\lib\rt.jar: error reading zip file
Z:\application\jre1.7.0_55\lib\rt.jar: ZIP_Read: error reading zip file
Z:\application\jre1.7.0_55\lib\rt.jar: ZIP_Read: error reading zip file
Exception in thread "Timer-0" Z:\application\jre1.7.0_55\lib\rt.jar: error rea
ding zip file

Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Timer-0"
```

Please let me know what can be the issue here?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with RMI. Don't tag indiscriminately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well ...
it appear you don't only load the application from your shared drive `Z:`, you also load the java runtime environment from that drive, more precisely from `Z:\application\jre1.7.0_55\`.

As a consequence, when you start your Swing application, your computer first load the java.exe in RAM (which is fast, then java.exe loads `rt.jar` ... which is quite heavy (around 49 Mb on my machine). And its during that download operation that your network hangs. Which prevents rt.jar from being a complete zip and output the message.

So, to avoid that, I would advise you to use a local JDK : obviously the jar of your swing application should still be downloaded ... but I don't think it's a 49 Mb one, no ?

Comment: I have made changes and assign local JRE instead of remote machine, however i am getting errors for other jars and application is throwing errors like class not found. So does it mean application needs to relaunch in this scenario or there can be something i can do to fix the issue?

Comment: Yes, for sure, relaunching application will help. However, your network appear to be quite ... unstable. I suggest you install the whole (JRE + app) on your machine and see what happens then.